# Meaning of "weird's another place"

Tags: phrase-meaning

There's a conversation in an episode of Midsomer Murders (S06E04) that's been bugging me. In full context:

```
Back to normal, then?
Normal's a bit weird round here, isn't it, Mr. Wilson?
No, Darren. Weird's another place.
```

I could never make sense of that last sentence. It was dubbed in Czech as "It's weird everywhere else." Is that an obscure idiom? A mistranslation?

Comment: It's not an idiom AFAIK. I see it as a joke meaning that there is another village (probably hypothetical) whose name is "Weird"

However we will probably never know what was in the mind of the scriptwriter. If it really bugs you, I suggest you email the author and ask them!

Comment: @chasly Good _comment_.  I would have added an alternative guess (I'm fairly familiar with MM and can't remember 'Weird' referenced in full-er (!) context). The translators into Czech, lacking detailed familiarity with the plot, do valiantly. I'm more familiar with Fantasy / SF Art depicting _other worlds_ and using fanciful non-referential titles like 'Other Worlds' / 'Another Place'. _Not_ here, not the familiar, not home ground. I see where the translators are coming from. ////  But the reference to the despised other village (your suggestion) is far more likely here....

Comment: The episode title  'A Tale of Two Hamlets' is an obvious play on words, but the feuding hamlets are called Upper and Lower Warden. It _might well_ be that the rival village is being referred to, but 'w/Weird' is probably best regarded here as an adjective being pressed into nominal service (as in 'Blue is the new grey' and snowclones. 'Undemanding/boring/easy is good'.) Not a name.

Comment: Figuratively, Weird can be a place if the past, as has been noted, can be a foreign country (where things are done differently).

Comment: My guess is that "normal's a bit weird round here"="this is a weird place (even once we've dealt with this week's murder)" and "weird's another place"="no, this place is quite normal and other places are much weirder". But as others say, it's not a common idiom, it may reflect something earlier in the script, and it's hard to be certain without the full script (which I don't propose to study).

Comment: I didn't find anything in the script (or even the show concept) that could in any way help contextualise this exchange.

Comment: A sleepy English village (of a type that doesn't really exist any more) where there are dozens of murders each year must surely be weird for some value of weird?

Comment: Midsomer is a county, though, not a village. This makes the particular village, Upper Warden, fairly normal (though perhaps the county is statistically anomalous...)